# Moving Datasource and Namespace bindings from Tomcat server.xml to property file

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi

I want to move my application specific database and namespace binding 
configurations from `server.xml`, `context.xml` to `database.property` and 
`namespace.property` file.

Initially I am using jndi-lookup to get the values from server.xml 
file.. I can use class `org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource` for 
this but I  still want to use JNDI-lookup.

How can I achive this .. any help please.

Initially my datasource setup was:

**applicationContexct.xml**

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="sampleDatasource" jndi-name="jdbc/test" cache="true" />
```

and in `context.xml` :

```
 <Resource auth="Container" 
      driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" 
      maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" 
      name="jdbc/test"
      password="test" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
      url="test......" username="test"/>
```

Now I want to use property file to store driverName, user ID, Password 
    etc. And hence I have created the property file and in applicationcontext I am using below entry

```
<bean id="sampleDatasource" 
     class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
     destroy-method="close"
     p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
     p:url="${jdbc.url}"
     p:username="${jdbc.username}"
     p:password="${jdbc.password}"
     p:maxWaitMillis="${jdbc.maxWait}"
     p:maxIdle="${jdbc.maxIdle}"/>**
```

But I have to coment out JNDI-lookup.. because it is no use now..

How can I achive the same thing using JNDI-lookup

I want my application should use

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="sampleDatasource" jndi-name="jdbc/test"  cache="true" />
```

to get the property from property file.

Comment: Do you want to use JNDI or not? `But I have to coment out JNDI-lookup.. because it is no use now..

How can I achive the same thing using JNDI-lookup`, doesn't make any sense.

Comment: yes I have to use JNDI-lookup, I said initially that I was using but now when moved datasources details to property file my code is no more link to jndi lookup to get the datasource details.. but I want a way where we can  use jndi-lookup and the drivername, userid,password details should be fetched from .property file intead of server.xml file...

Comment: is there any way to get the datasource details from property file using jndi-lookup

Comment: Only use of JNDI is to leave the creation of the object on the server. That means it has to be done on the server level. Why would you want to still put the configuration properties in source code? JNDI is useful in case you have multiple environments, like Dev/QA/Production, since server manages the objects we don't need to change the source and thus deployable artifact for different environments.

Answer (score 0):

Create jndi.properties file and put it in your JAVA_HOME/lib folder. JNDI will automatically discover and read from it.